# Passing a parameter to RelayCommand

Tags: wpf, mvvm, icommand, relaycommand

I'm experimenting with the `ICommand` and `RelayCommand` constructs. Looking around, I've put together the following code:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _executeMethod;
    private Func<object, bool> _canExecuteMethod;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> ExecuteMethod, Func<object, bool> CanExecuteMethod)
    {
        _executeMethod = ExecuteMethod;
        _canExecuteMethod = CanExecuteMethod;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecuteMethod != null)
        { 
            return _canExecuteMethod(parameter); 
        }
        else 
        {
            return false; 
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_executeMethod != null)
        { 
            _executeMethod(parameter); 
        }
    }
}
```

and I use all this from my main code as follows:

```
private bool CanExecuteMyCommand (object parameter) { /* do something here */ }

private void ExecuteMyCommand(object parameter) { /* do something here */ }

private ICommand _execMyCmd;
public ICommand ExecMyCmd
{
    get { return _execMyCmd; }
    set { _execMyCmd = value; }
}

ExecMyCmd = new RelayCommand(ExecuteMyCommand, CanExecuteMyCommand);
```

This works fine, but one thing I've not been able to find is how to pass a parameter to `ExecuteMyCommand`. I've tried something like:

```
ExecMyCmd = new RelayCommand(ExecuteMyCommand ("foo"), CanExecuteMyCommand);
```

but Visual Studio shows an error. Can anybody shed some light on this?

Thanks

Gianni

Comment: ***WHAT*** error?? Remember: we cannot see your screen, nor can we read your mind - you need to **SHOW US** if we should have any chance of helping you .....

Comment: You're right. If I try to pass the parameter using: ExecMyCmd = new RelayCommand(ExecuteMyCommand ("foo"), CanExecuteMyCommand); the error I get is "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Action<object>'

Answer (score 0):

Command parameters are typically passed by the control which binds to the command. Here is an example:

```
<Button x:Name="btn"
        Content="Click" 
        Command="{Binding ExecMyCmd}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=btn, Path=Content}"/>
```

This will pass the content of the button, which is `"Click"`, as parameter. Note that this is an example, so you could pass what ever you want here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't want to pass the parameter from xml, but from another piece of C# code. As per my initial question, I want to use something like: ExecMyCmd = new RelayCommand(ExecuteMyCommand ("foo"), CanExecuteMyCommand);